# Connect error in Daytime tcp server in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client

I'm new to network programming and I was following the book "unix network programming, the socket networking api." I was trying the first example of this book, a day time server. I wrote these codes for client and server. I executed the server.cpp from one terminal and client.cpp from another one.(./a.out 127.0.0.1) I'm supposed to get the time as output, but I keep getting connect error. Can someone please help me out?

Client.cpp

```
#include "unp.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int sockfd,n;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
char recvline[MAXLINE+1];
if(argc!=2)
{
    err_quit("Usage ./a.out <IPaddress>\n");
}
if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    err_quit("Socket error\n");
}
memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(13);
if(inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    err_quit("inet_pton error");
}
if(connect(sockfd,(sockaddr *) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0)
{
    err_quit("connect error\n");
}
while((n=read(sockfd,recvline,MAXLINE))>0)
{
    recvline[n]=0;
    if(fputs(recvline,stdout)==EOF)
    {
        err_quit("fputs error\n");
    }
}
if(n<0)
{
    err_quit("read error\n");
}
exit(0);
return 0;
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include "unp.h"
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int listenfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;
    listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(13);
    bind(listenfd,(sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listenfd,LISTENQ);
    for(;;)
    {
        connfd=accept(listenfd, (sockaddr *)NULL,NULL);
        ticks=time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"%.24s\r\n",ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd,buff,strlen(buff));
        close(connfd);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

unp.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/un.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/uio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define LISTENQ 1024
using namespace std;
void err_quit(const char *x)
{
    printf("%s",x);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: @user3541036 the code is correct. Does server listen on port 13 on interface 0.0.0.0? try sudo netstat -anlpl | grep 13

Comment: it's supposed to, but how can I check whether it's listening or not?

Comment: type in console (after you run the server): sudo netstat -anlpl | grep 13

Comment: ok, I did that. Now its displaying a lot of lines. All but two have connected and two have listening.
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13354    1800/gnome-session  /tmp/.ICE-unix/1800
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13353    1800/gnome-session  @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1800

What are the numbers?

Comment: your server is not listening, did you run it?

Comment: do a grep by name: sudo netstat -anlpl | grep YOUR_SERVER_PROGRAM_NAME, or do just: sudo netstat -anlpl | grep tcp

Comment: I did run it. Any idea what can be the error. I've posted the code.

Comment: I did it using the program name and nothing came up. Then I did sudo netstat -anlpl | grep tcp and got some connections. Should I only check the ones saying listening?

Comment: Please try run the code I've just posted, which wrapps a function calls with better error handling/reporting and do the same as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On UNIX systems only users with superuser authorizations ( "root" ) can bind to ports < 1024. Please try run this version which wrapps a function calls with better error handling/reporting with `sudo`. Next change port to something >1023 and try again without `sudo`.

```
#include "unp.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( 13); /* test*/

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) & servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    puts("listening...");

    for (;;) {
        len = sizeof (cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) & cliaddr, &len);
        printf( "connection from %s, port %d\n",
                Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof (buff)),
                ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff, sizeof (buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));

        //Write(connfd, buff, strlen(buff)); // normal version, write at once
        int i; // call Write for each one byte
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buff); ++i) {
            Write(connfd, &buff[i], 1);
        }
        printf( "writes: %d\n", i);
        Close(connfd);
    }
}
```

---

If you can't compile it, then try this:

```
#include "unp.h"
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int listenfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;
    listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(13);
    bind(listenfd,(sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listenfd,LISTENQ);
    puts("listening...");
    for(;;)
    {
        connfd=accept(listenfd, (sockaddr *)NULL,NULL);
        puts("accepted...");
        ticks=time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"%.24s\r\n",ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd,buff,strlen(buff));
        close(connfd);
    }
    puts("exiting...");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @darkrayshiro is "listening" printed when you run this?

Comment: Compilation error. Is the error because of "unp.h"? I didn't write the entire "unp.h" provided in the book. Is "Socket" different from "socket" or "Accept" different from "accept" in anyway?

Comment: yes, methods with big letters are used in "UNP" for error wrapping. I assume correct unp header

Comment: Ok, I'll search for the original unp.h

Comment: try second version that I posted, just printing view messages

Comment: tried the second one, it outputs listening. And on doing sudo netstat -anlpl | grep tcp I got
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42447           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3238/a.out      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1242/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      634/cupsd

Comment: is you server a.out? it is listening on 42447 for some reason... Run client to connect to 42447. Also try if something else is listening on port 13 ( grep 13)

Comment: Okey, both the code you posted and my original code are running now. Thanks. But none of them are running at port 13. I think I think I should try another port.

Comment: I wrote the server code in c++ file and then compiled it. I used grep on the ./a.out file. It's changing the port for some reason.

Comment: On UNIX systems only users with superuser authorizations ( "root" ) can bind to ports < 1024. What is this system?

Comment: UNIX, okey that was useful, It worked. Thanks :) Now I'll have to learn how to bind ports below 1024. But it worked when I used 3013.

Comment: run server with sudo. Nevertheless I suggest using big named functions from UNP for better error detection/reporting